# unable to bundle install bootstrap-sass -v '2.2.2.0' -

Tags: bootstrap-sass, bundle-install

New to RoR and taking the One Month Rails class (onemonthrails.com)

I'm trying to import bootstrap.

**ruby 2.0.0p247**

**rails 4.0.0**

Here's my Gemfile (showing only the 'bootstrap-sass'line) :

**Bootstrap Gem**

```
gem 'bootstrap-sass', '~> 2.2.2.0'
```

And this is the output when running 'bundle install'

```
Diegos-Air-2:omrails Diego$ bundle install
Fetching gem metadata from '...rubygems.org/..........'
Fetching gem metadata from '...rubygems.org/..'
Resolving dependencies...
Enter your password to install the bundled RubyGems to your system: 
Using rake (10.1.0) 
Using i18n (0.6.4) 
Using minitest (4.7.5) 
Using multi_json (1.7.8) 
Using atomic (1.1.12) 
Using thread_safe (0.1.2) 
Using tzinfo (0.3.37) 
Using activesupport (4.0.0) 
Using builder (3.1.4) 
Using erubis (2.7.0) 
Using rack (1.5.2) 
Using rack-test (0.6.2) 
Using actionpack (4.0.0) 
Using mime-types (1.23) 
Using polyglot (0.3.3) 
Using treetop (1.4.14) 
Using mail (2.5.4) 
Using actionmailer (4.0.0) 
Using activemodel (4.0.0) 
Using activerecord-deprecated_finders (1.0.3) 
Using arel (4.0.0) 
Using activerecord (4.0.0) 
Using sass (3.2.10) 
Installing bootstrap-sass (2.2.2.0) 
Errno::EACCES: Permission denied - /Users/Diego/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/bin/ruby_noexec_wrapper
An error occurred while installing bootstrap-sass (2.2.2.0), and Bundler cannot continue.
Make sure that `gem install bootstrap-sass -v '2.2.2.0'` succeeds before bundling.
```

My GitHub link: [github.com/dschmunis/omrails](http://github.com/dschmunis/omrails)

Thanks for the help!
Diego

Answer (score 0):

I've heard of some weird permission bugs right around this version

You could try installing directly into command line
`gem install bootstrap-sass -v 2.2.2.0`

and then run `bundle install`

Worst case scenario you should still be able to run `sudo gem install bootstrap-sass -v 2.2.2.0`

But you should be very careful with sudo.  It can leave you open to system vulnerabilities and it can lead to some weird problems down the road with gems being installed all over the place.  Long story short, don't use sudo carelessly.